# Css : overflow and width of div

Tags: css, html, overflow

Lets say my full text looks like:

`Hello, my name is David.`

I want a div that turns it into:

`Hello, my name i`

It's very simple, I just want the div have a width of, for example `90px`. So the rest of text doesn't show and it doesn't go to next line either.

```
.glass-text {
font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
width:90px;
overflow:hidden;
height:15px;
}
```

But above css is not working, The rest of text goes to next line :

```
Hello, my name i
s David
```

Comment: That should work as it is. You sure there isn't other CSS conflicting with it?

Comment: I tested your code but seems to be working without line break.. are you sure you are giving us all the information needed to debug your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to add `display:inline-block` to your CSS. Not sure why it would insert a line-break tho.

I'd even add these 2 lines to `.glass-text`:

```
text-overflow:ellipsis;
white-space:nowrap;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RuQFP/)**

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted ^_^

Answer (score 0):

`Hello,&nbsp;my&nbsp;name&nbsp;is&nbsp;David.` in html or `white-space: nowrap;` in css.

Comment: Neither of those will change anything.

Comment: In case he had min-height in effect or something.

Answer (score 0):

Use both white-space: nowrap and overflow: hidden

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary if you have a height specified.